# jQuery: Delay showing of a dropdown menu content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a dropdown menu that works fine. It goes like this:

1. Main menu items are in horizontal bar, then
2. When hover on any item, big dropdown box (with submenu links) is shown.
3. And here is my code for this:

HTML:

```
<!-- Based on Bootstrap -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">

            <li><a href="#about">First item</a>
                <div id="about-horizontal-submenu" class="horizontal-submenu">

                    <div class="submenu-container span3">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- and 4x similar div (to have 12 cols) -->
                </div>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#about">Dropdown</a>
                <div id="about-horizontal-submenu" class="horizontal-submenu">
                    <!-- 3x similar div (like above) and then: -->
                    <div class="submenu-container span3">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">I want to go here</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <!-- And then goes another main menu item... -->              
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $('.navbar .nav > li').hover(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.addClass('hover');
        var $submenu = $el.find('.horizontal-submenu');
        if ($submenu.is(':hidden')) {
            $submenu.slideDown(200);
        }
    }, function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.removeClass('hover');
        var $submenu = $el.find('.horizontal-submenu');
        if ($submenu.is(':visible')) {
            $submenu.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

---

### **Problem**

I think I need to add a little delay before both - sliding Down submenu on very first hover and - changing submenu content (when switching/hovering to another menu item).

**Why?**

When you hover on "Dropdown" and want to choose "I want to move here":

You have to go down from "Dropdown" item and then to the right - which is ok (but not very usable).

Problem is, when you go like the image is showing (from the "Dropdown" straight to the "I want to move here" - you catch "Third item" on your way and immidiatelly see the content that belongs to "Third item". And that's not very good.

If you could show me how to delay/ignore hover on my menu items for very short time, I would be grateful. (I found great example behavior of menu on: [http://FEI.com](http://www.fei.com/))

Comment: take a look at this article: [http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown](http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown).

Comment: ahhh you beat me to it!!! I was going to post this article as a reference. +1 :)

Comment: This seems to be it. However, I'm having some troubles to apply it for my case (with submenuDirection: "below"). Would you mind giving me some hint using my HTML (ids and classes)?

Comment: @NologLester Since the plugin logic isn't trivial, I would take a whole part of code from the working example as is, get it works on your page, and just then trying to customize it for your needs (changing html and styles, and checking if things still work after each save)

Comment: @Hristo yep, this is the only article, found it a while ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Ben Kamens from Khan Academy wrote an article regarding this exact problem, outlining how Amazon.com solved it. It is a great read!

- http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown

He also put together a jQuery plugin to solve this problem with a working demo. You can find it on GitHub here:

- https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim
- http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/blob/master/example/example.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function($) {
    var m;
    var timer="";
    var wait=200;
    active=function(){
        $('.navbar .nav > li').mouseover(function() {
            m = $(this);
            if(timer==""){
                test();
                unb();
                timer = setTimeout(reb,wait);            
            }
        });     
    }
    test = function(){
        $(".horizontal-submenu").stop().hide(300);      
        m.find(".horizontal-submenu").stop().show(300);
    };
    unb = function(){
         $('.navbar .nav > li').unbind('mouseover');
    };
    reb = function(){
        timer="";
        active();
    };
    $(".horizontal-submenu").hide(300);
    active();
});
```

Adjust 'wait' for your best timing; You can just copy and try on your script.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:- 
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

From this you need 2 lines on your web page to activate the hover to working properly
1) Loading script hoverIntent
2) Change from hover to hoverIntent in your jQuery

Answer (score -1):

please try setTimeout. It always does the trick.

Comment: I tried. I can't see it how, I really tried a lot of times. I'm exhausted, sorry